# When is the subspace of functions vanishing on a closed set complemented?

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Suppose $A$ is a closed subset of a smooth manifold $M$. Denote by $C(M)$ continuous functions with uniform norm. When is the subspace of functions vanishing on $A$ complemented in $C(M)$?

This is true if $A$ is a finite set of points (since then it's finite codimensional and closed) and if $A$ is a retraction of $M$.

An easier question I don't know how to answer is whether continuous functions on the disk that vanish on the boundary are complemented in all continuous functions on the disk.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After doing some research, I found out that the answer is always yes: the subspace $S$ of functions vanishing on $A$ is always complemented in $C(M)$, whenever $M$ is any compact metric space and $A$ is any closed subset.

To prove this, it is enough to show that there exists a family $\{\mu_x\}_{x\in M}$ of finite signed measures on $A$ with the following two properties:

(i) $x \mapsto \mu_x$ is weakly continuous.

(ii) $\mu_x=\delta_x$ for every $x \in A$, where $\delta_x$ is a point mass at $x$.

Indeed, if such a family of measures exists, then we can define a map $T:C(A) \to C(M)$ by defining $Tf(x):=\int_A f(y)\mu_x(dy)$. Then the image of $T$ is easily checked to be a complement for $S$. Indeed, the image is closed because $\|Tf\|_{C(M)} \geq \|f\|_{C(A)}$ trivially. It trivially intersects $S$ because any $g=Tf \in S \cap T(C(A))$ satisfies $$f(x)=\int_A f(y) \delta_x(dy)=Tf(x)=g(x)=0 \;\;\;\;for \;\;\;\;x \in A.$$ And finally, $S+T(C(A))=C(M)$ because we can write any function $f\in C(M)$ as $(f-\phi)+\phi$ where $\phi = T(f|_A)$. Then clearly $f-\phi\in S$ and $\phi \in T(C(A))$.

---

So let's prove that such a family of measures always exists for any closed subset $A$ of a compact metric space $M$. We are going to use a [generalization of the Tietze extension theorem](https://msp.org/pjm/1951/1-3/pjm-v1-n3-p04-p.pdf) which holds whenever the target space is a locally convex topological vector space.

Let $E$ be the space of all finite signed measures on $A$, i.e., $E=C(A)^*$. Equip $E$ with the weak topology, i.e., the topology generated by the family of seminorms $N_f(\mu) = |\mu(f)|$, with $f\in C(A)$.

Define a map $u:A \to E$ by sending $x \mapsto \delta_x$. Obviously this is continuous. Therefore by the Tietze extension theorem, $u$ can be extended continuously to a map $v: M \to E$. Then set $\mu_x:=v(x)$.

Comment: The harmonic function example is a special case of this construction, where $\mu_x$ is the harmonic measure seen from  (i.e., the hitting density of BM started at ). The case when  is a retraction of  is also a special case of this with $\mu_x = \delta_{r(x)}$ where :→ is the retraction.

Comment: In fact, if  is complemented in $C(M)$, then we can ALWAYS construct such a family of measures by defining $\mu_x(f)=\pi f(x)$, where  is the linear operator on $C(M)$ sending any $f\in C(M)$ to its projection onto the complement of $S$. That defines a measure by duality since $\mu_x$ is clearly linear and because $|\mu_x(f)|\leq \|\pi\|\|f\|$. Clearly that's weakly continuous in $x$. Moreover, $\pi f(x) = f(x)$ for $x \in A$ because $\pi-I$ maps onto $S$. Thus $\mu_x = \delta_x$ for $x\in A$. So this is an "if and only if" construction.

Comment: Both answers are very beautiful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

In the special case of the disk (where the closed set is its boundary), it seems like you have a complement consisting of functions that are harmonic on the interior of the disk and extend continuously to the boundary.

Indeed let $H(D)$ be the space of all such harmonic functions. Then $H(D)$ is a linear subspace because the sum of two functions which are harmonic on the interior is still harmonic on the interior; same story for scalar multiples. Also $H(D)$ is closed because any uniform limit of harmonic functions is harmonic.

Let $S$ denote the subspace of functions vanishing on the boundary. Then $H(D)\cap S = \{0\}$ because any harmonic function vanishing on the boundary is zero, by the maximum principle for instance.

Furthermore, any continuous function on the disk can be expressed as $f = \phi+(f-\phi)$, where $\phi$ solves the Laplace equation with boundary data $f|_{\partial D}$. Then clearly $\phi \in H(D)$ and $f-\phi \in S$.

Edit: I added another answer generalizing this construction to all closed sets $A$.